# Date math and formatting using JQL

Tags: date, jira, jql

I need to create a JQL filter that uses the current date and subtracts 2 months from it only using FixVersion (String).

Is there a way to basically say (this is pseudocode):

`fixVersion = "'"+(now().month() - "2m").toString()+"_2017"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible out of the box.

fixVersion is not a date field so you cannot perform any date operations on it in JQL.

For date fields, JIRA supports expressions like these:

- `duedate >= "2008/12/31"`
- `created >= "-5d"`
- `created > startOfMonth("-1")`

However, you can implement your own custom JQL function to support this, either by writing a custom add-on or by using a (commercial) add-on like Script Runner.

For more info check:

- [Advanced Searching - functions reference](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-functions-reference-764478342.html#Advancedsearching-functionsreference-startOfMonthstartOfMonth())
- [Advanced Searching - operators reference](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-operators-reference-764478341.html)
- [Script Runner on the marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview)
- [Script Runner - Custom JQL Functions](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/custom-jql-functions.html)